# Finding a position of a random word in a text file full of random letters

Tags: python, list, anaconda, spyder

I've been stuck on this for a few hours and can't seem to crack my way through it. I just want to find all the different times a word pops up in the text file attached as well as its location.index.

I thought converting the word and text file to a list might help but alas.
Here is what I have now. Here is the paste bin of the text file I am working with https://pastebin.com/MtjkvHaf

```
import string
import random
import os.path
def findWord(filename:str, word:str):
    if os.path.isfile(filename) == True:
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        fStr = str(f.read())
        location = []
        charList = []
        wordList = []
        i = 0
        j = 0

        #converts word to list
        for l in word:
            wordList.append(l)
    
        #converts text file to list
        for line in fStr:
            for c in line:
                charList.append(c)
        
        
        for i in charList:
            if wordList[0] == charList[i]:
                pos = i
                location.append(pos)
        print(location)
       
                
    else:
    print("File not found")
    
findWord("random_letters_05292022_1902.txt", "potato")
```

Comment: What are you getting from running with your given input?  Please edit your code such that it is properly indented.  Are those import lines supposed to be there?

Comment: @ewong I made some edits. Hope it clears things up. The imports don't need to be there - I just had them from testing out other things

Comment: ```for i in charList:``` iterates through charList, so each ```i``` is a string.  What you need is ```if wordList[0] == i:```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
import re
import os.path
def findWord(filename:str, word:str):
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("File not found")
        return
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        fStr = str(f.read())
        locs = []
        loc = 0
        while loc != -1:
            loc = fStr.find(word, locs[-1] + len(word) if locs else 0)
            if loc != -1:
                locs.append(loc)
        print(locs)

findWord('foo.txt', 'foo')
```

Input file foo.txt:

```
barbarfoobarbarbarfoobarbarbarfoobar
barbarfoobarbarbarfoobarbarbarfoobar
barbarfoobarbarbarfoobarbarbarfoobar
barbarfoobarbarbarfoobarbarbarfoobar
barbarfoobarbarbarfoobarbarbarfoobar
barbarfoobarbarbarfoobarbarbarfoobar
```

Output:

```
[6, 18, 30, 43, 55, 67, 80, 92, 104, 117, 129, 141, 154, 166, 178, 191, 203, 215]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Where can I read up more on:

"loc = fStr.find(word, locs[-1] + len(word) if locs else 0)"

Have not seen it before and want to know how it works. Thanks!

Comment: More specifically how does the -1 work here?

Comment: Here are the docs for [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) which say in part: "Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found ... Return -1 if sub is not found".